# I need alternative of dart millisecondsSinceEpoch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, flutter, dart

We are developing a chat system between mobile and web using firestore. from mobile side we used flutter and from web side we used vue js. but we are facing the problem of timestamp, the document create using timestamp from both side are not in ascending order.
I want the document to be created an ascending order on bases of timestamp.

From flutter side we used

`DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()`

and from vue js side we try these functions

`+new Date / new Date.getTime() / new Date.valueOf()`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can simply use `Date.now()`, to get milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: We have fixed it using "new Date.getTime()", actually it was a problem of local time. thanks for your time.